# error loading a native .so file in android project

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an error loading in a native library.  I've included the libthirdparty_jni.so file under 2 folders in libs, one for amr and the other for arm7.  What are the first steps that I can take to debug?

`JNI_OnLoad returned bad version (-1) in /data/app-lib`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


  static { 

    System.loadLibrary("thirdparty_jni"); 

  }

}
```

Comment: Did you build those `.so` files using the NDK?

Comment: no I got them from decomiling an apk

Comment: JNI_OnLoad for a given .so can return whatever it likes. Without knowing which library you're using we can't help you. You should either try to get the source to see what error will cause JNI_OnLoad to return -1, or get the documentation for the library.